# Emulating 2.4 GHz transmission without ICs

Tags: rf, emulator, nrf24l01

I'm looking for a way to emulate 2.4G transmission without using complex IC components like nrf51/24. I imagine a gramophone recording, but broadcasted on 2.4 GHz into space. No need to receive anything, just send into the wild.

Is it technically possible to pre-record the transmission onto EEPROM and just read and send it to TX antenna with arbitrary intervals?

Thanks!

Comment: cavity magnetron?

Comment: What do you mean by "emulate" 2.4 G transmission. *Emulating* something means doing something similar that is not actually the thing you are emulating. So it sounds like you are talking about *not actually* transmitting 2.4 GHz, but then it sounds like you do actually want to transmit 2.4 GHz.

Comment: An EEPROM counts as an IC, surely?

Comment: @pjc50 - an EEPROM is not a particularly complex IC, at least conceptually, in comparison to the digitally interfaced 2.4 GHz transceivers cited in the question.

Comment: Could you tell us what you need this for? It will be hard to get a decent answer without more details of the problem you are trying to solve. But anyone trying to transmit anything would want to make sure it got transmitted, so you must be planning on having a receiver. Or maybe you just want to affect an existing receiver, or just trying to create a jammer. Which is it?

Comment: @Ricardo - actually there are lots of fairly legitimate 1-way RF systems - beacons, status transmitters, etc.  To some extent, it's only with the 2.4 GHz transceiver chips that a lot of systems which don't really need to be bidirectional become so as a side effect of the "transmitter" and "receiver" using the same circuitry, possibly modulo the presence of a power amplifier in one but not the other.

Comment: @ChrisStratton - Maybe I wasn't very clear. I know the OP wants to build a transmitter. I was just curious as to how he or she plans on testing if it is transmitting anything at all. My guess was that he or she already has a device with which he or she plans on using for testing the transmitter. This is the RF version the famous phylosofical question: if you trasmitted your signal and nothing received it, did you really transmit anything?

Comment: @Ricardo This is for low-cost analog Bluetooth LE beacon in connectionless mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is technically possible to play back pre-recorded or pre-sampled signals at a baseband or a very low IF and upconvert them to 2.4 GHz.

The upconverter could be built with analog electronics; potentially discrete though you may not want to rule out using MMICs.

The bandwidth and center frequency of your baseband / low IF sampler would depend on the bandwidth which your system needs to access.  Most 2.4 GHz systems hop frequently, but if yours does not you only need the bandwidth of a single channel.  If it hops, you'll either need a wider band system which can encompass all the used channels, or to coordinate channel switching in the upconverter.

For moderate bandwidth, an analog tape deck could be substituted for the sampled playback system.  For really low bandwidth, a mechanical gramophone could.

Note that building this system from general-purpose building blocks is likely to be much more work and expense than using an IC purpose-made to perform this type of function in low-cost consumer gadgets.  You'd basically be building a software-radio transmitter, just without running the software modulator in real time.

Comment: Thank you very much, that's exactly the information I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the receiver, you will have to produce an appropriately modulated signal using a base carrier frequency matching your receiver and using the receiver's modulation technique.  You can't just send a series of "ON/OFF" pulses.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_modulation#Digital_modulation_methods

Also, storing the data for a useful transmission would require a good amount of ram which must be accessible at a very high speed.

Comment: The amount of storage and access speed would really depend on the necessary bandwidth you need to upconvert.